# Why can't we use $MathJax$ in username?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, display-names

Why can't we use $MathJax$ or other characters in username?

I'd recommend 
this on SE network.

Comment: For simple enough MathJax expressions, you can use Unicode characters to mimic it in a username.  For example, I'm pretty sure "ℶ₁=ℵ₁" would be a perfectly acceptable (though perhaps annoying) username.

Answer (score 11):

Besides the fact that it seems totally unnecessary, I'd imagine it's a combination of

- It would make @-replies basically impossible.
- Most sites on the SE network don't have MathJax (which, by the way, is not the same thing as LaTeX).
- Too much hassle for the SE team to implement compared to the "benefit".

You already can use markdown, MathJax, images, etc. in your "About Me" section - an impressive amount of expressive ability. What is so bad about requiring a single aspect of your account to be plain text?

Comment: Aah! I also wanted to ask about special characters ... `shifted numerics`